# Dell vostro 1310 touchpad doesn't wotk!

Tags: wireless, touchpad, dell

I just installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 system. Touchpad and wireless don't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Same problem on ASUS S550CM

Answer (score 0):

You have probably done this, but just in case:

Wireless: have you enabled wireless from 'System Settings'?
Touch-pad: again, have you looked at Touch-pad and Mouse in the same place?